# Convert specific property from Record into Array in Typescript/Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, ecmascript-6, typescript-typings

Need to convert Record Type in Typescript/Javascript to Array with specific property

```
const store: Record<ProductID, ProductObject> = {
        'france': productObject:{
                                 present: 'in_stock',
                                 amount: 23,                            
                                },
            'uk': productObject:{
                                 present: 'in_stock',
                                 amount: 20,                            
                                },
         'japan': productObject:{
                                 present: 'no_stock',
                                 amount: 0,                         
                                },                      
    }
```

**Output**: Creating New Array. Adding new key as **'country'** & take only **'amount'** property from store Record type.

```
const newArrayFromRecord = [
                            {country: 'france', amount: 23},
                            {country: 'uk', amount: 20}
                            {country: 'japan', amount: 0}
                           ]
```

I have tried with [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and then pushing in Array. But all require unnecessary code. Is there any efficient way to do..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one possible way to achieve the objective:

```
  Object.entries(store).map(([k, v]) => ({
    country: k,
    amount: v.amount
  }))
```

Code Snippet using JS:

```js
const store = {
  'france': {
    present: 'in_stock',
    amount: 23,
  },
  'uk': {
    present: 'in_stock',
    amount: 20,
  },
  'japan': {
    present: 'no_stock',
    amount: 0,
  },
};

console.log(
  'result: ',
  Object.entries(store).map(([k, v]) => ({
    country: k,
    amount: v.amount
  }))
);
```

And, here's a [TypeScript Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBNICcCmAuGAlJoEBMA80CAlmAOYA0MAhmAJ4B8MAvDAN4BQMMA5AGYI1gSbmg5cuAB2QQkYKGm4kA+vGABrbuU7iqAWxABXOWgBMAZi1cAvpZ4GNo7ZOmz5PZao22uew8ZgmAAy2NtrcAFZUEjQibE4wUkgy-txgICpQIOqa8b5GbsHaoVYA3OzsoJAgADZIAHTVIKQAFGHSBtVuOVwA8gBG4VhQda7ESc3wyACU2nW6Ua3iMM0A2mowlABuMAC6U8yMzWJLMKD5CLRoat46+vlom3V5cvFWM1wzU2XsQA).

Answer (score 1):

You could just loop over the store object using a `for in` loop.

Or mapping it with `Object.keys`.

Aside from that I don't think there is really a more "efficient" solution.

```js
const store = {
    france: {
        present: "in_stock",
        amount: 23,
    },
    uk: {
        present: "in_stock",
        amount: 20,
    },
    japan: {
        present: "no_stock",
        amount: 0,
    },
};

const result = [];
for (const country in store) {
    result.push({ country, amount: store[country].amount });
}

const result_2 = Object.keys(store).map((country) => ({
    country,
    amount: store[country].amount,
}));

console.log(result);
console.log(result_2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Object.entries` and `destructuring`

```js
const data = {
  'france': {
    present: 'in_stock',
    amount: 23,
  },
  'uk': {
    present: 'in_stock',
    amount: 20,
  },
  'japan': {
    present: 'no_stock',
    amount: 0,
  },
};

const res = Object.entries(data).map(([country, { amount }]) => ({
  country,
  amount,
}));

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Where is the Record type here?